# WPF and Windows Forms Interoperation

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

**WPF and Windows Forms Interoperation**

> Description on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751797(v=vs.110).aspx):

In a WPF user interface, you can change the z-order of elements to control overlapping behavior. A hosted Windows Forms control is drawn in a separate HWND, so it is always drawn on top of WPF elements.

*But I would like to know there is no private way to solve it?

Comment: Can you tell me why you need to host Windows forms over WPF?  Any specific reason that forced you to move with windows form hosting?  Not relevant to the question, just curious to know

Comment: Well, it might be relavant... as the best solution is not always to do what we were thinking to do.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is known as the **airspace** problem (because WinForms elements take all of it).

There was supposed to be a fix around .NET 4.5/4.6 but it never made it to production ([source](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2012/11/wpf-45-airspace-problem-solved.html); there are others if you google it). There has been no word as of yet that Microsoft plans on addressing it.

This article might help with ways to get around it: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

My first recommandation would be to replace the Windows Form control by an equivalent WPF control.

Second recommandation would be to accept the limitation and do not overlap any WPF control over the Windows Form control.

In some case, you might be able to use multiple top-level Windows to work around the limitation. You then have to write some code to properly synchronize the location or the apparent activation state of Windows...

I have never done that between Windows Form and WPF but I have done 2 top-level windows in Windows Form so that part of the UI could be semi-transparent (the purpose was to be able to overlap another application (maybe a PDF viewer) so that we can "copy" curves from existing charts).